Word Find/Replace Wildcards: Add quotes at the beginning and end of text block that contains paragraph marks
I have a table and each cell has text in it. Some cells are single lines, some two lines, some multiple lines, The ones with multiple lines use hard paragraph marks (^13) but have no paragraph mark at the end of the block of text. For example:
This text block has<^13>
three lines with<^13>
short line breaks.

I want to add a straight quote at the beginning and end of these text blocks so the final result looks like this:
"This text block has<^13>
three lines with<^13>
short line breaks."

I've tried a bunch of combinations to find the whole block, with no luck. For example, the following only finds individual lines:
(*)^13(*){1,}
(*^13)(*){1,}
(*^13*){1,}
(*^13){1,}(*)

I also tried a multiple-pass approach where I add a quote to the beginning of every line that ends with ^13, then remove the quote from every line except the first. The problem with that is I cannot find the last line to add a quote to the end. I've tried:
(^13)(*)
(^13*) 
(^13*{1,})

They only find the ^13 and not the text that follows. The last example above finds the first character of the line after the ^13, but not the whole line.
I truly stumped. Any ideas?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm not sure how else I can describe what I'm trying to do. What exactly needs clarifying?

You may want to consider using VBA for this.
